# Direct Product of Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I just want to know if the internal direct product of 2 abelian groups is also abelian? Is there an existing theorem on this?

Because if this is true, then I am done with what I am proving on indecomposability of groups. Thank you.

Comment: Internal and external direct products are isomorphic to each other (when corresponding direct factors are isomorphic), and external direct products of abelian groups are abelian, so...

Comment: So the internal direct products of Abelian groups are also abelian?

Comment: Thank you @Lee Mosher! :)